# I didn’t get the meaning of “an informal sleep over bang up bash for any who wanted to stay“please can anyone. explain?

Tags: meaning, british-english

Explanation of “an informal sleep over bang up bash for any who wanted to stay”

The exact quote is

> After my wedding I was ill and missed most of my reception, **an informal sleep over bang up bash for any who wanted to stay**. When I felt well enough to join the party it was over. The only ones still awake, waiting to warm over the dinner I had missed that they saved for me, was my new Mama and Papa.

[Source](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meanest-thing-your-mother-in-law-did-to-you/answer/Kim-Mitchell-16?share=5c3b9f0d&srid=hnyk7)

Comment: You can look up "sleep over", "bang up", and "bash" and probably get the meaning.

Comment: I can’t get the meaning albeit knowing the individual words’ meaning

Comment: punctuation: ***an informal sleepover, bang-up bash***.

Answer (score 5):

We can figure out most of it from context.

- A wedding reception is a type of party held after a wedding.
- Bash is another word for party.
- The party was for "any who wanted to stay", or in other words open to everyone.
- A "sleep over" means an overnight event.
- "Bang up" is British for excellent.

So the author was ill and missed the post-wedding party, which was informal, overnight, excellent, and open to all.

Comment: There might have been an implicit restriction on the guest list:  "open to all [who attended the wedding]".

Comment: @Jasper Good point.  I suspect that Mr. Moustafa was mostly checking to see if this unusual phrase held special meaning.  As far as I can tell, it's just a bit of wordplay.  Hopefully we cleared that up!